# Linux dmesg errors, memory issue?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory

I am seeing following messages on my dmesg report and the system load is always spiking.

> INFO: task java:17047 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
>         Not tainted 2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64 #1
>
> sqs[48389]: segfault at 40 ip 0000000000423a29 sp 00007ffcaea16110
>   error 4 in sqs[400000+6a000]
>
> stat[48906] trap divide error ip:4044cd sp:7ffd6fa40e40 error:0 in
>   acxstat[400000+11000]

Can someone please help me understand this message? Here is my memory usage:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I mean, technically this is a memory error; but it's not the memory error that you're implying. `ip 0000000000423a29` is the [instruction pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter), and `sp 00007ffcaea16110` is the [stack register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_register). You then have `error 4`:

```
$ errno 4
EINTR 4 Interrupted system call
```

The `trap divide error` is a division error; looking over the source, [here is an example](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e0d072250a54669dce876d8ade70e417356aae74/arch/sh/kernel/traps_32.c#L604).

Is this an out of memory error? No, because I haven't seen any `OOM` errors. Linux memory is a tricky beast; [you should understand how to interpret the results](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

What you're experiencing here is an application error; not a Linux error. The only possible way it would be an actual memory error is if you do a memtest on the memory and find that you have bad memory.

Comment: Thanks @bbb31 
Can I say this application errors are causing the server load to spike and the above java process to get blocked